github actions doesn't recognize configuration variables
I am using the very simple workflow:
name: Deploy Frontend


# env:
#   REACT_APP_API_URL: ${{ vars.REACT_APP_API_URL }}
#   CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: ${{ vars.CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS }}
env:
  REACT_APP_API_URL: MY_REACT_APP_API_URL
  CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: MY_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS


on:
  push:
    branches: [main, staging, frontend]
    paths:
      - 'frontend/**'
      - '.github/workflows/deploy_frontend.yml'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pages: write       # Added for GitHub Pages deployment
      id-token: write    # Necessary for actions/deploy-pages
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Debug REACT_APP_API_URL
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo -e "\e[32m@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\e[0m"
        echo -e "\e[32mREACT_APP_API_URL=${REACT_APP_API_URL}\e[0m"
        echo -e "\e[32mREACT_APP_API_URL=${CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS}\e[0m"
        env


which writes MY_REACT_APP_API_URL=MY_MY_REACT_APP_API_URL (and so on) if it is hard coded, or MY_REACT_APP_API_URL= if I am trying to get it from vars.REACT_APP_API_URL.
This makes me think I defined it incorrectly in github.
Here is what my github looks like, and please note env doesn't recognize anything defined in the variables section.

None of the environment variables are available during the github actions run.

What did I define wrong and how to make it right?

Please have a look at the following discussion: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/56123

@Bademeister Works! found it by asking GPT about "inputs" after your deleted answer. Thanks!

@Bademeister I do wonder why the gh-pages environment didn't provide even the repository variables.

I was confused at first. The branch restrictions do not determine for which branch an environment is used in the workflow. The branch restrictions only determine whether an environment can be applied to a branch. I set the branch via input. Of course, you can also set the branch via logic. You musst to set the environment name explicitly.

Answer found here (but really it took hours with GPT and a hint from @Bademeister).
I had the environment set to gh-pages whereas it should be set to
 environment:
      name: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'prod' || 'staging' }}

So the jobs section should be
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pages: write       
      id-token: write   
    environment:
      name: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'prod' || 'staging' }} # <--- this
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4

And suddenly all variables go in the workflow

What I can not see in your workflow is that you also set the environment name. I set the environment name via an input.
Here is an example.
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: choice
        description: Choose environment
        options:
        - stage
        - production
jobs:
  deploy:
    environment: ${{inputs.environment}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    # ..


ok, sounds interesting. Which name do I need to choose? I thought it should be automatic according to the workflow branch that runs, I have the branch configured for the environment. Could you link the relevant doc please? I don't know what to look for

Also, I see you nested it under workflow_dispatch, but I want it valid no matter what the trigger was

This is very different from mine and I am new to this, kind of hard to understand what's what and what needs to change or not

This doesn't really make sense as an answer. How would you access REACT_APP_API_URL?

I have not configured any restrictions on my environments. So I set the environment via input. If you have configured your environments with restrictions, there is probably something wrong with your pattern that is preventing the environment from being resolved. You could try my example first to narrow down the error. If my example works, then you know that something is wrong with your restrictions.

I haven't worked that much with Environments yet. Please have a look at the following discussion: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/56123

I was confused at first. The branch restrictions do not determine for which branch an environment is used in the workflow. The branch restrictions only determine whether an environment can be applied to a branch. I set the branch via input. Of course, you can also set the branch via logic. You musst to set the environment name explicitly.
